# How to hide HtmlElement in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a webbbrowser control that navigates to a page that contains an image,
and i want to hide or delete this image from my webbrowser.
I've tried to set on DocumentCompleted event the method below with no luck:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("imgToHide").Style = "display:none";
```

**How to hide an htmlelement from a webbrowser control?**

My programing language is C#.

Below is my code:

```
 private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(oURL);  
    }
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //imgCancel is the name of t he image to hide
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("imgCancel").Style = "display:none";
    }
```

Comment: That should work.  Can you show us the page?

Comment: May be try 
style ="visibility:hidden"

Answer (score 1):

Try making an html file that contain the script :

```
function SetHidden()
  {
   window.document.all["hiddenText"].style.display="block";
   return "ok";
  }
```

After that place in your C# code :

```
Results = (string)WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SetHidden");

MessageBox.Show(Results);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i am late.but it may help somebody who need it.
You can change the outerhtml of that specific image at run time.Like that

```
myDoc = this.webBrowser1.Document;

myDoc.GetElementById("imgToHide").OuterHtml = "Changed html here!";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `runtimeStyle`

```
IHTMLElement2 domElement = element.DomElement as IHTMLElement2;
domInspectBox.runtimeStyle.visibility ="hidden"; // if you want to hide it
domInspectBox.runtimeStyle.display = "none"; // if you want to empty its place
```